# What is backfilling in data?

Tags: database

There's some hits on Google, but nothing satisfactory. For example, the first hit for me is

> The process of completing multiple diary or other data reporting forms
> at the same time, instead of within the requested time interval,
> resulting in retrospective or memory-biased data.
> [Source](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/data-backfilling/79000#:%7E:text=1.,retrospective%20or%20memory%2Dbiased%20data).

Can anyone give a bit more complete of a definition with an example?

Comment: Keep it simple: it's just filling in missing data thats not there. For example, let's say you have a table in your relational database, and it's been in place for a while so it has a few thousand rows. Now some new requirement comes along, causing you to need to add a new column and adjust the application to require this new value. Those existing records aren't going to already have values for that column, because it's new. If you have some way of obtaining or deriving that data and updating those records to have values for that column, the act of updating existing records would be backfilling